# How can I output an array in sequence to various div's?

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried many methods, the latest gives no output. Here are my codes. At other attempts, I got the array to display but not as wanted. Examples of how it's to display are these(I capitalized the strings which are from the array):

NOTE, each is a separate div which has been looped to give them similar attributes like class, The array output with the strings is added as the text content of each of the divs

My best output

The FIRST SECOND THIRD question

The FIRST SECOND THIRD question

The FIRST SECOND THIRD question

Expected Output

The FIRST question

The SECOND question

The THIRD question

```js
const myArr = ['first', 'second', 'third'];
for (let o = 0; o < myArr.length; o++) {
  console.log(`The ${myArr[o]} question`)

  const divOne = document.querySelectorAll('.eachSection-class div:nth-of-type(1)');
  for (j = 0; j < divOne.length; j++) {
    divOne[j].classList.add('divOne-class');
    divOne[j].textContent = `The ${myArr[o]} question`;
  }
  console.log(divOne);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <main>
    <section>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </section>
    <section>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </section>
    <section>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </section>
  </main>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not totally sure what you want the code to do, but this will likely give you enough to do what you want

```js
const main = document.querySelector('main'); 
main.classList.add('main-class');
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('main section');
sections.forEach(section => section.classList.add('eachSection-class'));

const myArr = ['first', 'second', 'third'];
myArr.forEach((val,i) => {
  const content = `The ${val} question`;
  console.log(content)
  const firstDiv = sections[i].querySelector('div'); // assuming as many sections as array length
  firstDiv.classList.add('divOne-class');
  firstDiv.textContent = content;
})
```

```css
.divOne-class { border: 1px solid red; }
```

```html
<body>
  <main>
    <section>
      <div></div>
      <div>First section, second div</div>
    </section>
    <section>
      <div></div>
      <div>Second section, second div</div>
    </section>
    <section>
      <div></div>
      <div>Third section, second div</div>
    </section>
  </main>
```

Comment: //variables
const main = document.querySelector('main');
main.classList.add('main-class');
console.log(main);

const eachSection = document.querySelectorAll('section');
for (i = 0; i < eachSection.length; i++) {
 eachSection[i].classList.add('eachSection-class');
 console.log(eachSection[i]);
}
console.log(eachSection);

Comment: @ZeroHour That does not change the rest of the code. See update

Comment: This is not the method I was going with but yours also works.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your selector has no matches. I suppose you forgot to give the `section` elements their class attributes.

The main issue with your code is that for each element of the array (outer loop), you iterate *all* `div` elements you want to use. That means you are setting the text of these `div` elements all to the same text, and then repeat this job for the next array element.

Instead, you should just have one loop, and use the index for both the array element and the `div`.

NB: `o` is an unusual name for a loop variable, so I renamed it.

```js
const myArr = ['first', 'second', 'third'];
const divOne = document.querySelectorAll('.eachSection-class div:nth-of-type(1)');
for (let i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++){
    divOne[i].classList.add('divOne-class');
    divOne[i].textContent = `The ${myArr[i]} question`;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <section class="eachSection-class">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </section>
    <section class="eachSection-class">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </section>
    <section class="eachSection-class">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </section>
</main>
```

Comment: I gave them a class attribute via javascript. I have hav updated the code above as a comment to reflect that

Comment: I don't know what you updated, but when I run your code, the selector doesn't match anything. I trust you have that working at your side, but since it is not reflected in the question, I had just mentioned it as a first remark. It is not the main point of my answer though.

Comment: In response to your NB:,  I had another loop that used the letter I so I went with o to avoid confusion.

Comment: Yes, but still `o` is unusual as a name. Common is to then use `j`, `k`.

Comment: Those were taken too.

Comment: That would only be a problem if you had nested loops with `j` and `k`, which isn't the case. If you properly limit the scope of variables, then a loop variable only exists in the loop itself and does not conflict with another loop that is not nested.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250739/discussion-between-zero-hour-and-trincot).